# How to find the sign of the determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A_2=\begin{bmatrix}2^2&1\\3^2&1\end{bmatrix}$ and $A_3=\begin{bmatrix}3^2×2^2&3^2& 1\\4^2×3^2&4^2&1\\5^2×4^2&5^2&1\end{bmatrix}$, and so on.

Then, $\det A_2 = 2^2-3^2 <0$. Applying row operations $R_3 \rightarrow R_3 - R_2$ and $R_2 \rightarrow R_2 - R_1$ the matrix $A_3$ becomes
$$\begin{bmatrix}3^2×2^2 & 3^2 & 1\\3^2(4^2-2^2) & (4^2-3^2) & 0\\4^2(5^2-3^2) & (5^2-3^2) & 0\\  \end{bmatrix},$$ which gives us $$\det A_3 = 3^2(4^2-2^2)(5^2-4^2)-4^2(4^2-3^2)(5^2-3^2)<0.$$

Que: How can I find the sign of $\det A_n ?$ Because when I approach higher orders, the expression for the determinant goes complicated.

Any Help or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Thinking of the determinant as a signed volume, in $2$ dimensions, the basis vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are 'flipped', hence they have negative signed volume. In $3$ dimensions, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are flipped while $v_3 = e_3$ which doesn't affect the sign. So show that there are an odd number of sign changes for $n$ dimensions.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there any alternative technique to solve this ?

Comment: Can you explain "and so on"? I can see little relation between $A_2$ and $A_3$ I'm afraid.

Comment: @ancient mathematician, by 'so on', I mean preserving the pattern, we can define more elements of this sequence, like $A_4, A_5, \cdots .$ Can you please explain the relation between $A_2$ and $A_3$ or just give a hint. I will try to solve it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @ancient mathematician you got good points.  To your delight, now I provide the connection between A_2 and A_3 by stating the "pattern" in plain English thet you need to preserve .  In a way, this is a pattern recognition problem.

Comment: @prince, I'm sure there are other methods.  But that is for you to dig further into uncharted territory.  For me, it is already a day's work. What do you expect?

Comment: I m trying too to guess the relation. Please let me know if u find it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let  $A_3=\begin{bmatrix}3^2×2^2&3^2& 1\\4^2×3^2&4^2&1\\5^2×4^2&5^2&1\end{bmatrix}$,

and so on.

Def A matrix $A_n$ is in negative form if det A = |A| < 0.

Theorem  Every matrix having first, jth and nth row of the form (1) to (3) is said to be in negative form.

$$\begin{align}
A_n(1,*)= [n!)^2 |(n!)^2/(2!)^2| (n!)^2/(3!)^2| .. |n^2| 1]          \tag{1}\label{eq1} \\
A_n(j,*)= [((n+j)!/n!)^2|((n+j)!)^2/(2!)^2|((n+j)!)^2/(3!)^2| .. |(n+j)^2| 1]\tag{2}\label{eq2} \\
A_n(n,*)= [((2n-1)!/n!)^2|((2n-1)!)^2/(2!)^2| ((2n-1)!)^2/(3!)^2| .. |(2n-1)^2 | 1] \tag{3}\label{eq3}\\                                                                                   
\end{align}$$

The above rules determines what is the pattern for which a matrix A_n is in negative form by pure inspection.  You still need to prove it rigorously.  But at least you got some intuition and confidence going forward.

In plain English, $B_n$ is in negative form:

1. if it is product of square of n-1 consecutive  positive integers in the first column,
2. if it is product of square of (n-2)consecutive  positive integer in the
   2nd column.
3. continue the process for column k=1,2, ... to n-1
4. the last column is an exception as it contains all 1s.
5. From 2nd row on, you replace each number p  in a
   product pqr... by p+1, q+1,r+1, ...  etc.  Exception : and except last term
   which contains  difference square of integers.  This holds true for all for
   row index i>1

A good example of a matrix of oder 3 matrix in negative form  is $A_3$ given above.
Given A_3 is in negative form, we now wish to show $A_4$ given below is also in negative form.

$A_4=\begin{bmatrix}4^2×3^2×2^2&4^2×3^2&4^2& 1\\5^2×4^2×3^2&5^2×4^2&5^2& 
1\\6^2×5^2×4^2&6^2×5^2&6^2&1\\7^2×6^2×5^2&7^2×6^2&7^2&1\end{bmatrix}$

Proof

By Gaussian elimination using the following elementary row operations,

R4−R3→R4, R3−R2→R3, R2-R1→R2

$A_4=\begin{bmatrix}4^2×3^2×2^2&4^2×3^2&4^2& 1\\4^2×3^2×(5^2-2^2)&4^2×(5^2-3^2)&5^2-4^2& 0\\5^2×4^2×(6^2-3^2)&5^2×(6^2-4^2)&6^2-5^2& 0\\6^2×5^2×(7^2-4^2)&6^2×(7^2-5^2)&7^2-6^2& 
0\end{bmatrix}$

Suppose $A_3$ is in negative form, det($A_3$)<0 and $A_4$ can be expressed as

$A_4 =\begin{bmatrix}x^T &1\\B_3& z\end{bmatrix}$

where x=[$x_1 x_2 x_3$] is a 3x1 row vector and z =$[0 0 0]^T$ is a 3x1 column vector.

$B_3$ is in negative form, det$A_4$ = det $B_3$ < 0

By induction if $A_{n-1}$ is in negative form, so is $A_n$ and |$A_n$| < 0.

Q. E. D.

Comment: why is $B_3$ in negative form? I understand that you are applying induction on $n$, but please explain, why is your theorem applicable to $B_3?$

Comment: B_3 is in negative form1. if it is product of square of n-1 consecutive  positive  in the first column,2. if it is product of square of (n-2)consecutive  positive  in the first column...and it consists  of single integer. 3. the last column is all 1s.

Comment: What about $5^2-2^2, 6^2-3^2.7^2-4^2$ in the first column?  These numbers being in the first column of $B_3$ dont allow us to use theorem for $B_3$.

Comment: The theorem should be allowed to bend a little bit to say  the  the product of square except "the last term",  which can be "difference of the square". Keep in mind one of the row contains the spoiler because it is negative which makes the determinant go negative. compare this with $A_3$ see if you can spot the pattern of except the last term which is actually difference of square!!!

Comment: have u got anything?